# Query that selects IDs of pair of subsidiaries that have exactly the same movies

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So, I have an intermediate table in MySQL called "Inventory", with two PKs: idMovie and idSubsidiary. That table looks like this:

```
----------------------------------
idMovie (int) | idSubsidiary (int)
----------------------------------
0             | 0
2             | 0
1             | 1
3             | 2
----------------------------------
```

**I want to select the IDs of the pair of subsidiaries that have exactly the same movies.**

For that, I was thinking about something like this:

```
select distinct inv1.idSubsidiary, inv2.idSubsidiary
from    inventory inv1
join    inventory inv2
on      inv1.idSubsidiary <> inv2.idSubsidiary
where not exists (

    SELECT i1.idSubsidiary, i1.idMovie , i2.idSubsidiary, i2.idMovie 
    FROM inventory i1
    INNER JOIN inventory i2 ON i1.idMovie = i2.idMovie 
    WHERE (i1.idSubsidiary= inv1.idSubsidiary and i2.idSubsidiary= inv2.idSubsidiary
    AND i2.idSubsidiary IS NULL

)
```

The result I'm looking for would be something like this:

```
idSubsidiary | idSubsidiary
---------------------------
0            | 1
3            | 4
```

So, subsidiary 0 and 1 have the same identical movies on the inventory, same with 3 and 4.

However, the previously shown query is not working. Basically, the query looks up for couples of SubsidiaryID's on Inventory and then runs a nested query to find if the first Subsidiary have any movie that the second Subsidiary does not have. If they don't, it selects both.

However, the nested query is not working. As I said, I want to do a left join of the same table without the inner part.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Could you provide with a sample input data and expected output

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sorry, I tried my best to make it much clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method in MySQL is to do double aggregation:

```
select movies, group_concat(idSubsidiary) as subsidiaries
from (select i.idSubsidiary, group_concat(idMovie order by idMovie) as movies
      from inventory i
      group by i.idSubsidiary
     ) s
group by movies
having count(*) > 1;
```

Each row in the result set is a set of movies with the set of ids that have exactly those movies.  Those are the duplicates.

Comment: I want to avoid using count here because there could be two subsidiaries that have 196 movies but those movies aren't necessarily the same.